# AdMob ads in screenshots for Google Play

Tags: google-play-store, ads

I am developing an application that has some ads using AdMob. What is the recommendation for screenshots when preparing for the Google Play publishment? Should all the ads be removed before taking the screenshots?

And, maybe this is a programming question for regular stackoverflow, is there an easy way to just remove all of them before running the app in the emulator and taking the screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend adding placeholders for the ads (a rectangular box with the text 'AdMob ad goes here').  I've seen quite a few other developers do this.  It lets the user know there will be ads, and where the ads will be placed in the user interface.

If you remove the ads, and then the user gets your app and it shows ads, expect negative reviews.  By disclosing ahead of time that your app has ads, you stand a better chance of not having as many negative reviews for having ads.

Comment: Great answer, I did not know that was a way of doing it but it makes sense. Thanks!